# Entity Framework Many to many between custom entity and Identity user never inserts row

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I have a Many to Many relationship defined between my custom class (Department) and my User class based on Identity 2 defined as below. This generates an extra table, which is all good. However this table is never populated, and from my Profiler i can see that it never creates and executes the SQL to insert the row. What am i doing wrong?

```
    public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Navn")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Mindst acceptable antal skemaer")]
    public int ApprovalThreshold { get; set; }
    public List<ATVisit> Atvisits { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Actionplan> ActionPlans { get; set; }
    public int? QuestionSheetTemplateIdFK { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("QuestionSheetTemplateIdFK")]
    public QuestionSheetTemplate QuestionSheetTemplate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

    public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

I even tried with Fluent API:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Departments)
            .WithMany(c => c.Users);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Users)
            .WithMany(c => c.Departments);
```

I am using repositories, and because of this i have to find the User in the Department Repository, otherwise i'll get an error telling me it comes from 2 different Contexts. This is my Department Repository method for updating:

```
        public bool FindUserAndAddToDepartment(Department entity, string userId)
    {
        var user = context.Set<User>().Where(x => x.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
        entity.Users.Add(user);

        return true;
    }
```

This is the method that handles everything

```
        public ActionResult EditUser(UserViewModel model)
    {   //vi starter med at fjerne alle Claims der er department
        List<Department> depList = new List<Department>();
        var user = UserManager.FindById(model.Id);

        if (user.Departments == null)
            user.Departments = new List<Department>();

        foreach (var selectedDepartment in model.SelectedDepartments)
        {
            depList.Add(departmentRepo.GetById(selectedDepartment));
        }

        foreach (var d in depList)
        {
            if (user.Departments.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == d.DepartmentId).SingleOrDefault() == null)
            {
                departmentRepo.FindUserAndAddToDepartment(d, user.Id);
                departmentRepo.Update(d);
            }

        }
        departmentRepo.Commit();

    }
```

Comment: What is `user.Users` in `FindUserAndAddToDepartment`? Also use only one of the 2 fluent api configurations.

Comment: i'm not quite sure where you see user.Users. If you mean entity.Users it is the collection of Users on the department.
Thanks for the tip on the Fluent API, not used to using it, however i only added the second after the first did nothing.

Comment: In the FindUserAndAddToDepartment function. You search for a user not for a department.

Comment: Yes that's because the Department is already found and is being passed by parameter, however to add the User, it has to be connected to the same context, that's why i load it there.